# How to Import a Class From Android Source While Developing an Android Application

Tags: java, android, eclipse, frameworks, import

I want to use a java class from android/frameworks/base/.... How can I import the class to my project in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(cross-posted from [android-developers](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/t/d60a291f5e481bfe))*

The Settings app is part of the firmware. It has the ability to use classes that are not part of the Android SDK.

If your "application about display settings" is an SDK application, you cannot use `HdmiService`.

If your "application about display settings" is part of the firmware, more relevant support lists can be found here:

http://source.android.com/community/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Just use the import statements as you do when you import every other package.

For example if you want to use the [AndroidHttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html), then the following import will do it:

```
import android.net.http.*;
```

Comment: Eclipse does not recognizes the class that I want to use. For example, look at the source code of Settings app in Android. Open "DisplaySettings.java" and see it imports "com.slsi.sec.android.HdmiService". Now try to import it in your project. What do you see? This is gonna be the time you understand me I think.